# How to include user_id (foreignKey) when posting an new record?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm new to python Django rest-framework, I'm facing this problem when creating a new address:

```
null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (21, full name, 123456789, any, any, any, any, any, any, f, null).
```

This is The address model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserAddress (models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User, related_name='addresses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
full_name = models.TextField(default='')
phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
city = models.TextField()
province = models.TextField()
street = models.TextField()
description = models.TextField()
postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
is_default = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'user_addresses'
```

And this is the serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from user_action.models.address import UserAddress


class UserAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = UserAddress
    fields = ['id', 'full_name', 'phone', 'city', 'province',
              'street', 'description', 'postcode', 'country', 'is_default']
```

And the POST method:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def createUserAddress(request):
user = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = UserAddressSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        newAddress = serializer.save()
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post request is unable to save User details. Try to pass user instance to serialiser.save() method.

Comment: the solution was serializer.save(user=request.user),